# Datomic best practice for storing or passing db connections

Tags: database, connection, datomic

I'm using Datomic (for the first time) and enjoying it fairly well.

I have a number of functions for getting things from the db, such as user.  I see two ways to do this:  passing the DB URI around for each route and creating a new connection each time, or storing a single connection and reusing it.

```
;; The uri-passing version...
(defn connect [uri] (try (datomic.api/connect uri
(defn get-user [uri user-id]
  (let [db (connect uri)]
    (...)))
```

Or...

```
;; The db storage version
(defonce db (atom nil))
(defn get-user [user-id] (...))
```

I don't really like passing the uri around all the time... it feels like it clutters the function calls.  What's a best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, middleware is a good way to do this in a ring app.  Here's some examples and info.

https://gist.github.com/bobby/3150938